# Как препятствовать скроллу в мобильном виде

Tags: javascript, css

Вот в хроме есть инструменты разработчка и там есть вид с мобилки. Короче у меня съезжает топ фиксированный когда включаю мобильный вид и скорлю вниз. Скрины прикрепил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайте тут: http://afisha.net.ru - причем на главной не съезжает нифига(ничего) ?Съезжает на http://afisha.net.ru/fullpost/133

Comment: вы это лучше на смартфоне посмотрите ....devtools конечно хороший инструмент но вёрстку под него я не видел ещё

Comment: да вроде на мобилке не съезжает, спасибо

Comment: Возможно просто какие-то стили закешировались, бывает